# How to restore mysql users

Tags: mysql, restore

I dropped accidentally all the users exist in my mysql DB and when I refresh the admin page I had this error :

> Error
>
> MySQL said:
>
> ## 1130 - Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server   phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the
>
> server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username
>   and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond
>   to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

How can I restore those users without losing my data ?

Comment: How do you want to restore dropped data? Do you have a backup? Do you have ssh access? Did you tried  127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?

Comment: Because I still have the data folder with all DBs.

Comment: what I want for now is just recreate a root user with all priveleges and have access to the those DBs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set an init file with the correct SQL to create/set a password for the root user, and then restart the server with the `--init-file` parameter.

Follow the directions [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html).  Any SQL in the init file will be run, so you can create more users if you need to also.